# Proper way to display custom line item fields on checkout form

Tags: views, commerce

Is there any proper way to display custom line item fields on checkout form?

I know that I can add each custom field one by one into views but it's complicated when I have few line items with dozen conditional fields and you need always to remember about it.

I found out that I can add to checkout view "Rendered Commerce Line item", formatter: "render complete entity" and choose necessary fields by adding custom view mode by hook_entity_info_alter. That's great with one little problem. It's always rendering number before my fields (it's line item id?).

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of that number (maybe altering some hook?) or other way to list out all line item fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem is to create custom `entity.tpl` ([Theme developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) can suggest filename) and remove printing out entity title.